# Qt4 connect QThread signal with main thread slot

Tags: multithreading, qt4, signals, slots

All right here we go:

This is all over the internet, but it does not seems to be working for me, the thing is I have two threads, Worker and p4, p4 sends a time to wait and other params to the worker, and I want that to be processed in a different thread, but then update the main thread with the results.

so, Worker.h looks like this:

```
 #include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    int time;
    int actual_weight;
    int supported_weigth;

    Worker();
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void process();

signals:
    void finished();
};
```

Worker.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Worker::Worker()
{
}

Worker::~Worker(){

}

void Worker::process(){

    cout << "sleep!" << endl;
    sleep(this->time);
     cout << "done!" << endl;
    //more_nonsense_stuff();
    emit finished();

}
```

and then in my main thread I have this:

```
QThread* t = new QThread;
Worker* w = new Worker();
w->time = this->transactions[i].time;
connect(t, SIGNAL(started()), w, SLOT(process()));
connect(w, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(update_gui()));
w->moveToThread(t);
t->start();
```

the thing is that the SLOT update_gui() is defined in the main window header and implemented in the .cpp, but it never gets to execute.

I have tried attaching Qt::DirectConnection, and the gui updates, but when worker is finished... the whole program closes.

I've looked [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/threads-mandelbrot.html) but didn't worked for me (or I didn't understand), also looked at [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) but that says what I'm trying to do is unsafe??

please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me.  There is likely something wrong in code you haven't posted.  In particular, it would helpful to see more code from your main window class.

Comment: can that be that `w->moveToThread(t);` is called too late and the actual connections' type is "direct"? :)